# rosjava and eclipse projects

Tags: rosjava, eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

why do rosjava projects with generated eclipse files (./gradlew foo:eclipse) require a rosjava project and why does this require several "apache_xmlrpc_*" projects?

Is it possible to use a rojava eclipse project without these dependencies?

Best regards,
Andreas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30585/rosjava-and-eclipse-projects/) by [andreasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/1333/andreasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2012-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're not developing rosjava, then you can create an Eclipse project that will depend on the required jars instead of linked projects. Simply add an external dependency on ros.rosjava_core:rosjava:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT and the transitive dependencies (e.g. apache_xmlrpc) will be pulled in automatically.

Otherwise, AFAIK the answer is no. The eclipse plugin will generate dependencies as project dependencies.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0